# Update a field of a record based on values in the other fields of the same record

Tags: mysql

I have three columns in a table:

```
| PLANNING | ASSESSMENTANDDATA |TOTAL
| One Word | One Test          | 
| Two Word | Two Test          |
```

I need to update the 'TOTAL' column for each record so that if the 'PLANNING' column contains 'One' then add 1 to the running total for the row.  Then, if 'ASSESSMENTANDDATA' contains 'One' then add another 1 to the running total for the row and then update 'TOTAL' with 2. Next record would be - if 'PLANNING' column contains 'Two' then add 2 to the running total for the row. Then if 'ASSESSMENTANDDATA' contains 'Two' then add another 2 to the running total for the row and then update 'TOTAL' with 4.

```
| PLANNING | ASSESSMENTANDDATA |TOTAL
| One Word | One Test          | 2
| Two Word | Two Test          | 4
```

I have this so far: (Work in Progress - I believe far from complete)

```
SET @runtot := 0;
SELECT 
id,
SUM(CASE 
        WHEN PLANNING like '%One%' THEN @runtot := @runtot + 1
        WHEN PLANNING like '%Two%' THEN @runtot := @runtot + 2
        WHEN ASSESSMENTANDDATA like '%One%' THEN @runtot := @runtot + 1
        WHEN ASSESSMENTANDDATA like '%Two%' THEN @runtot := @runtot + 2
    END)
        FROM RUBERIC
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: your  code  .. seems not related  to the sample described in your question  ..   ..update your question and  add  a coherent data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Does the posted answer work ? If not, please comment on the answer about the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that you need to use `Group By` with `Sum()` aggregation. If we were to use `Case .. When` expressions, then it would have been nested expressions instead.

However, We can exploit a MySQL behaviour of implicit conversion and typecasting, such as, `LIKE %..%` operator's return value can be consider as 0/1. We can use it for adding, instead of writing multiple `Case .. When` expressions.

Try the following instead:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  PLANNING, 
  ASSESSMENTANDDATA, 
  (@runtot := @runtot + 
             (1 * ((PLANNING like '%One%') + (ASSESSMENTANDDATA like '%One%'))) + 
             (2 * ((PLANNING like '%Two%') + (ASSESSMENTANDDATA like '%Two%')))
  ) AS TOTAL 
FROM RUBERIC
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @runtot := 0) AS user_init_vars
```